# Сохранение скачанного файла Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, файлы

Цель: скачать файл и сохранить в папке Downloads 
При попытке открыть файл для записи таким способом

```
FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput(folder + "/" + name_pic, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Выдаёт мне такую ошибку: 
E/Error:: File /storage/emulated/0/Download/picture.png contains a path separator 
Как исправить?
Вызываю класс так:

```
String url = "http://192.168.1.7/static/picture.png"; 
new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(url);
```

В манифесте прописаны права для INTERNET,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE и READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 
За помощь буду очень благодарен

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            System.out.println("Downloading");
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            System.out.println(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            String folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
            String name_pic = "picture.png";
            //OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(root+"/downloadedfile.jpg");
            Log.e("Status", "output not opened");
            FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput(folder + "/" + name_pic, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Log.e("Status", "output opened");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
                //System.out.println(count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();
            Log.e("e", "End");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
    /**
     * After completing background task
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        System.out.println("Downloaded");
        System.out.println(file_url);
    }

}
```

Comment: `openFileOutput` - пишет в приватную папку приложения и принимает только имя файла без подпапок. Вам нужно сделать, как в закомментированной строке `new FileOutputStream(folder + "/" + name_pic)`. И для Android 6.0 и выше разрешения в манифесте недостаточно, нужно ещё запрашивать во время выполнения: [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=ru#java)

Comment: Благодарю!!!!
Всё работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно сделать, как в закомментированной строке

```
new FileOutputStream(folder + "/" + name_pic)
```

И запросить разрешение во время выполнения

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            1);
```

Спасибо, [woesss](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11515/woesss)!